# how to resize columns in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

during design time i cannot figure out how to resize the datagridview columns in vb.net!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. Go to the Design view
2. Click on the grid
3. Select "Edit Columns"
4. Add a column
5. The new column will be shown in the Edit Columns dialog, go to the Properties part of it and in the layout part of the properties, there's a Width property. Set there the number of pixels that you want to have.
6. Click Ok and you'll see the new column with the width you setted.

For bound columns you have to follow a very similar process.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2008 (using C# although I hazzard that VB is the same):
Right-click the DataGridView, Edit Columns then foreach column enter the width.
Done.